# I am having trouble getting my SSRS line chart to Show data for both months when both months are selected. I.E (04/01/21 -04/30/22)

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a line chart that I can not get to show both dates on the graph.  IE if I select 04/01/21 - 04/30/22

I can only one april shows up on my graph and it graphs both april months even though they are in different years

I tried changing the Horizontal axis options to month so it would recgonize that each seperate month throughout the year really i do not know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to provide much more info. Please provide some sample data as text (as it comes out of your dataset query) and also show your report design including any relevant settings such as chart series and category definitions etc. At the moment it's difficult to understand what your issue is. Please read this for guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Alan Due to Company Sensitivity I can not share data or query I do not know how to better Explains This. I realized SO was not going to be able to Help

Comment: you can surely share dummy data? just swap out customer names or trademarks etc with apples and oranges. You don't need to share a query, just script out the sample data in the same structure as your dataset query. And then create a simple version of your report that uses that dummy data with just the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.